# Is year*10000 + month*100 + day monotonic?

Tags: math, date, time

Simple question: is `year * 10000 + month * 100 + day` always increasing? For example, today would is 20121011 and tomorrow is 20121012, which is 1 higher. Is this always the case? I've heard of some crazy stuff happening with dates and times before, but I'm no expert.

And just to preempt some responses - I know this is far from the best way to be handling dates/times. I can't use proper libraries for the problem I'm working on without jumping through some serious hoops, and I'd prefer a simple solution.

Comment: This is better asked at http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: To be honest, I wasn't positive where to post it. It's not really about math; I know that for all common cases it's obviously monotonic. It's more about edge cases - weird things that have happened with dates and times like changing time zones, daylight savings, leap-seconds, etc. And I've seen a few good posts about that kind of thing on stackoverflow before.

Comment: You don't have to care a lot about time zones and daylight savings if you work with UTC time instead of local time.

Comment: What's the maximum value the year variable can represent? :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it must. `0<day<100` and `0<month<100` always. Provided you use the full year, e.g. 2012 and not 12.

And you should not compare times from different zones, then you're fine.

Answer (score 3):

In the real world every now and then someone will adjust the system time backward.  That someone can be another program, in particular an NTP daemon.  If the adjustment occurs at midnight, it is possible that your date value reaches 20121014 and is then followed by 20121013.  If you are making software that should never ever crash or malfunction, you need to prepare for the possibility of system time going backwards.

Answer (score 2):

It's monotonic in the sense that two different dates will sort numerically in time order.

Comment: Only sensible interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of your scope, but don't forget time zones.

It's truly amazing how we think it is somehow easier to change the definition of time rather than our interpretation of it.  :[

Comment: Huh... So in one sentence you claim the following: That definitions are in a way more fundamental than interpretations so we should assume them to be harder to change. That `f(x)` is in some way a change of definition of `x`. And that it shall be obvious to us what the interpretation of time is or how to change it. Amazing, indeed. ;)

Comment: Let's take two people that are two time zones away from each other.  They do not go to work at the same time, but their watches claim they do...  clock time is redefined dependent upon location rather than just making different use of the same clock time in different places.  For example, one of the above people could go to work at 6am while the other goes at 8am.  This way the two hour time difference between their start of work times is actually presented in the stated time.

Comment: Of course, daylight savings time is even worse. Instead of simply going to work an hour early or later depending on the amount of daylight, we instead redefine what 8am is... Would it be so bad to go to work at 8am for part of the year and 7am for another part? Certainly it is easier than changing all your clocks and writing code that can handle all these politically defined shifts. :[

Comment: Ah, now your remark makes sense, which I thought you made in the context of the question. And I agree, there are a lot of ways conventions make our life harder. Their origin often is historical. The original definition of 12 o'clock is "sun at zenith", long before clock synchronization was possible.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, that would seem to work, in that it will always increase. All 3 pieces (day, month, year) are monotonic increasing, as long as you use the full 4-digit year, I see no apparent issues. (I'm assuming these are either all in the same time zone, or converted to some standard timezone).

I'm quite lost as to why you would need to go this route, but it should work.